# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="uID"]"}

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I build auto-login program by python
but, i don't know everything

so, What can I do in this situation?

html code

```
<input type="text" name="uID" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="ID" autocomplete="off" required="" tabindex="1">
```

my code

```
my_id2 = 'id'
my_pw2 = 'password'

driver.find_element_by_name('uID').send_keys(my_id2)
driver.find_element_by_name('uPW').send_keys(my_pw2)
```

error massage

```
NoSuchElementException
    Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="uID"]"}
      (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

Comment: Hi there what seems to be the problem?

Comment: try using xpath or css selector

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use locate your element use this

```
#css
driver.find_element_by_css('input[name=\'uID\']'.send_keys(my_pw2)

#or

#xpath
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name,\'uID\']'.send_keys(my_pw2)
```

driver.find_element_by_name is used to find an element that has the "value" attribute filled.